# How can I query just the month and day of a DATE column?

Tags: sql, date, casting, informix

I have a date of birth DATE column in a customer table with ~13 million rows. I would like to query this table to find all customers who were born on a certain month and day of that month, but any year.

Can I do this by casting the date into a char and doing a subscript query on the cast, or should I create an aditional char column, update it to hold just the month and day, or create three new integer columns to hold month, day and year, respectively?

This will be a very frequently used query criteria...

**EDIT:**... and the table has ~13 million rows.

Can you please provide an example of your best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it will be frequently used, consider a ['functional index'](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0325.htm).  Searching on that term at the Informix 11.70 InfoCentre produces a number of relevant hits.

You can use:

```
WHERE MONTH(date_col) = 12 AND DAY(date_col) = 25;
```

You can also play games such as:

```
WHERE MONTH(date_col) * 100 + DAY(date_col) = 1225;
```

This might be more suitable for a functional index, but isn't as clear for everyday use.  You could easily write a stored procedure too:

Note that in the absence of a functional index, invoking functions on a column in the criterion means that an index is unlikely to be used.

```
CREATE FUNCTION mmdd(date_val DATE DEFAULT TODAY) RETURNING SMALLINT AS mmdd;
    RETURN MONTH(date_val) * 100 + DAY(date_val);
END FUNCTION;
```

And use it as:

```
WHERE mmdd(date_col) = 1225;
```

Comment: It would be preferrable to use an index, as there's ~13 million rows. I'm wondering what is the cost of querying on MONTH(birthdate) and DAY(birthdate), versus adding 3 separate integer columns and populating them with the month, day and year, while retaining the original date column. Birthdate is a value that seldom changes unless a data entry error was made.

Comment: It's going to depend on the queries you really run.  If you're looking to ensure that the punter is at least 21 years old, you'll need the date in full.  If you're looking at birthdays, then the day and month components make sense.  I'm not sure how often (if ever) you'd want year and month or (even less plausibly) year and day of month.  So I doubt that a year column would be worthwhile; if you do a lot of birthday searches, then month and day might make sense, but I'd still do measurements, and I'd look at a functional index before storing separately.

Comment: With 13 million rows, you're going to have a lot of repetition in an index on month/day (35,000 entries per day of the year).  On its own, it is moderately selective (0.3% selectivity is not bad).  If combined with other conditions, then it's likely they'll provide alternative indexes.  It really depends on the queries you'll execute.

Comment: Well, the query is to determine one week before, which of the ~13 million customers have a birthday comming up so we can send them a $100 gift! :-)  How did you arrive at 35,000 birthdays per year if there are only 365 or 366 birthdays per year? The birthday distribution for ~13 million customers doesn't distribute equally.

Comment: I arrived at 35,000 entries per day of the year from 13,000,000 / 365.

Comment: Interesting, now we can sample the ~13M customers to see which is the most frequent birthday. BTW, I noticed the onconfig.instance file in FC6 now includes DSS parameters. How can I tune onconfif for maximum query performance? I'm the only one executing DSS queries, have 4GB's of RAM (need 1GB for Windows), 1TB disk, dual processors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21111/discussion-between-frank-computer-and-jonathan-leffler)

Comment: I tested your equation and it works. 2012-12-13 minus 1994-12-13 gave me 6575, so no Y2K problem in that date arithmetic, but if you use YMD2- then it thinks 12-12-13 is 1912-12-13. There's no DBCENTURY for 4.10, so I use YMD4- for entering, displaying and calculating all dates.
Why until 2018-03-01?

Comment: 4.10 certainly predates DBCENTURY, by most of a decade.  Why 2018-03-01?  If there had been a Y2K problem (which there isn't directly), then 18 years earlier than 2018-03-01 is 2000-03-01 so the (hypothetical) Y2K glitch would have been immaterial.

Comment: As to birthdays on FEB-29, they would have to be converted to FEB-28 or MAR-01 for queries to return them on non-leap years, although they could be left at FEB-29 because the queries purpose is for sending a $100 gift one week before their birthday? Uses for month/year queries would be, for example, to calculate a products age in years and months since several manufactured items, like computers, TV's, etc. are printed with the month/year they were manufactured.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how frequently you do this and how fast it needs to run you might think about splitting the date column into day, month and year columns. This would make search faster but cause all sorts of other problems when you want to retrieve a whole date (and also problems in validating that it is a date) - not a great idea.

Assuming speed isn't a probem I would do something like:

```
select *
FROM Table
WHERE Month(*DateOfBirthColumn*) = *SomeMonth* AND DAY(*DateOfBirthColumn*) = *SomeDay*
```

I don't have informix in front of me at the moment but I think the syntax is right.

Comment: I populated the customer table from a text file in which the date was in char format with a dash as its delimiter, example: 12-13-2012. The birthdate is static, so would it be useful to load this date into a date column, plus three separate integer columns for month, day and year respectively?

Comment: It depends how often you're really going to be look for birthdays as opposed to date of birth.  If birthdays will be looked up sufficiently frequently to warrant it, then consider storing the day and month components of the DoB as either one or two columns (jointly indexed if there are two columns). One trick is to note when 'leap babies' get their birthday in a non-leap year.

Comment: As a generally accepted tradition, leap year babies celebrate their birthdays either one day before or one day after the birthday if the year is not a leap year. I wait for weekends to celebrate mine! Leap babies wouldn't be a problem, as the queries will mostly be on month and day. Their birthdates would have to be on a valid date anyway, example: 02-29-2012 for it to have been entered into the date column. If the date would've been invalid, the HPL or dbload would've rejected it and I would've known from looking at the load logfile. So I can query the table for all leap year babies :-)

Comment: @Jonathan, for leap babies birthdays: `table.LeapBaby CHAR(1), SELECT * FROM table WHERE LeapBaby = "Y"`